# IOS: Open an application from another application without URL schema

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have an iOS project 'myApp' that contains pod dependencies. Is it possible to convert the entire application to a framework or a Pod file (I don't know what is the best in this case), and open it from other application ? Like from a main application I press a button and I launch 'myApp'.

From my researches I only found URL schema solutions.

Comment: What I did for now, I created a framework that contains all source files of my iOS application "app1" and converted it to a Pod using Cocoapod. from anoher application demo, when I press a button I call that Pod and the application starts. The problem is that I think it can't be done like this, and I cant publich this Pod to the public because I don't want to put my source code in public.
My Goal is to have a Pod containig an entire application, that users can install the pod and launch the app1 from their application.

Answer (score 0):

No, apps can only launch other apps via URL schemes.

Embedding your App's code into a framework and distributing it via Coacoapods is certainly an option, but then your other application would simply contain all the code of that framework and execute that in its context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. "Embedding your App's code into a framework and distributing it via Coacoapods" thats what Im trying to do. so that the user when he press a button, he don't have to install another app on his device. I mean the main application is like a container of other sub-applications as libraries. I'm asking because on android it's doable.